# Do we say "turn the strength of the fan up/down"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We say "**turn the volume of the TV up/down**".

Do we say "**turn the strength of the fan up/down**" as the fan has a few buttons for you to adjust the strength of the air blow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sure, why not?](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/turn-up_1)

> turn up
>
> to increase the amount of sound, heat, or light produced by a piece of equipment by pressing a button or moving a switch

"The amount of airflow" isn't on the list, but it's a rather natural extension of that definition. You can either turn *the strength of the fan* up, or, more naturally, just *turn the fan up*.

Comment: (also, it's a little funny to me that the definition includes buttons and switches, but not *dials* - y'know, the things that actually *turn*).

Comment: I would use _speed_ rather than _strength_.

Comment: @KateBunting - Agreed.  I've never heard anyone use *fan strength* in place of *fan speed*.  Never.